# Are there compassionate exemptions from isolation requirements for travellers to England and Wales (in June 2021)

Tags: uk, covid-19, quarantine

As of 15th June 2021, most of the world is on the UK government's "Amber" list. Travellers from these countries arriving in England or Wales are required to enter self-isolation (quarantine) for ten days.

There are various exemptions that apply, but they are almost entirely based on your job or which top-level sporting event you're participating in.

What I can't find is whether there are compassionate exemptions, for example, to be able to visit a dying relative.

[There *are* compassionate exemptions for *managed quarantine*](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/exemptions-from-managed-quarantine-for-medical-and-compassionate-reasons#compassionate-exemptions) - not self-isolation, but quarantine in a registered facility - for travellers from "Red" list countries.

Since there are compassionate exemptions for the stricter quarantine, I'd expect to find them for the less strict quarantine - but I'd like to know for sure!

Answer (score 4):

While it doesn't explicitly list "compassionate exemptions" the [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-quarantine-when-you-arrive-in-england) does list some example exemptions for Quarantine-At-Home that allow you to leave:

> **Exceptional circumstances**
>
> You can leave your accommodation in certain exceptional circumstances. This includes needing to:
>
> - get basic urgent necessities like food and medicines where you cannot arrange for these to be delivered
> - travel to a COVID-19 testing site
> - access critical public services including social services and services provided to victims (such as victims of crime)
> - move to a different place for quarantine where you can no longer remain where you are
> - There may be other exceptional circumstances that allow you to leave your place of quarantine.
>
> You could get advice from a medical or other professional to help decide whether your circumstances are exceptional and require you to leave your place of quarantine.
>
> Even if you have an exception, you must continue to follow the general restrictions that apply.